# Position of the LIDAR inside a box

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get the position and uncertainty of my LIDAR sensor inside a box. For position: x, y values in mm and angle in degree, for uncertainty: σx, σy values in mm and σθ in degree. I am using RaspberryPi with [RPLIDAR A2](http://bucket.download.slamtec.com/aaf96dddba2f6a9baa03261628c01af9fc2f866c/LD310_SLAMTEC_rplidar_datasheet_A3M1_v1.0_en.pdf) and programming with C++. I want to get the position of the LIDAR inside the parent box.

**Update 1:** I am getting data (distance and angle) from the LIDAR and plotting in Matlab. But I need to find the position of the LIDAR in the box. I don't need exactly codes, just steps through it can help me.

**Update 2:** Here's the plot from Matlab (this reading isn't from inside a box though).[image] Currently the sensor is always at the center if I move it. I want to get the position of the sensor as the box is in a fixed position the thing moving is the sensor itself.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. For clarity, are you asking how to use a R.Pi to read the values output from the LIDAR? First read of the first sentence had me thinking you were asking how to physically get it positioned inside a box. Also, in the future please include a link to the .pdf datasheet. I've edited it in for you this time.

Comment: I have the values. I need the position of the LIDAR inside the box.

Comment: "I don't know where to start" is a little too vague for anyone to help you.  Do you know C++?  Have you used a RaspberryPi before?  Do you know how to physically wire the sensor to the Pi?  Do you understand what digital interface the sensor uses?  How to write software for that interface?  How to interpret the RPLIDAR datasheet to parse the data stream?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance if I'm wrong since I haven't had to set up a LIDAR system. If you have the datastream with angles and distance, isn't that all you need for calculating a position? Assuming you have known reference for where 0 degrees is pointing in reference to whatever you've got it mounted on. If 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees all have the same measurement, you're in the middle. If you reference those measurements to the points in between, you can map shape of the box and your orientation in it. Right?

Comment: Yes I get it now. I want to make the box permanent, so if I move the sensor, I can see that the box isn't moving, what's moving is the sensor.

Comment: Do you know the size of the box beforehand? Is there anything else inside the box?

Comment: I actually don't know the size of the box and it may contain things inside it.

Comment: Read about "resection", a surverer technique

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, it's about maths, not Electrical Engineering.

So far as the LIDAR is concerned, it is at the centre of the universe, and it defines a zero degree axis.  All the coordinates it returns are relative to that centre and that axis.

It probably returns polar coordinates (r, θ), where r is range and θ is angle relative to the axis.  It should be a simple bit of trig if you would prefer them converted to (x, y).

Your task is to perform a rotation and translation on those coordinates to align them with what you have chosen to be the centre of the universe - the box.  The tricky bit is working out what that translation and rotation is.

If you are in a box, you should find that the points neatly fall into straight lines.  You will need to work out some way to determine which points are in which lines.  Perhaps use a Hough transform.  Or just pick a group of sequential points from the LIDAR and determine whether they are close enough to forming a straight line.

Once you know where the lines are, relative to the LIDAR, you can work out the rotation to turn the lines to where you want them, then the translation to move everything relative to the centre of the box.

Be aware that if the box is a simple rectangle or square, then there is always some ambiguity.  If some sneaky person turns the LIDAR off for a moment, rotates the whole thing 180° and turns it on again, you will have no way to know.

Comment: I used a Hough transform for robot localization at university, it worked decently well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a map of the room you can use something like a particle filter to estimate your location. This is called [localization](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNtI6mjdfaAhVh3IMKHcOoAvgQFghfMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cim.mcgill.ca%2F~yiannis%2Fparticletutorial.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2SQpYlzvp51s_bKRXZPfTQ). There are many papers, resources, and tutorials on the subject.

It's also used by driverless car algorithms to estimate the location of a car.

[image]
Source: [Toward Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/helping-a-self-driving-car-localize-itself-88705f419e4a)